# Laravel 4 Eloquent 'hasMany': how to set the default lookup value rather than primay key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to retrieve all the comments under the post_id(post1) in page:

```
//localhost/posts/post1/
```

table comments

```
id:int[primary],  comment:varchar,  post_id:varchar, comment_id:varchar
1                 this is a comment post_1           comment_1
```

table posts

```
id:int[primary], post_title:varchar, post_id:varchar
1                this is post title  post_1
```

model comment.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $This->belongsTo('Post');

}
```

model post.php

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
```

controller postsController.php

```
 public function show($id)
    {
       $comments = Post::where('post_id','=',$id)->first()
                   ->comments()->where('post_id','=',$id)->get();

    }
```

When I visit //localhost/posts/post1/ , no related comment is displayed. The SQL runs as below:

```
select * from `posts` where `post_id` = 'post1' limit 1
select * from `comments` where `comments`.`post_id` = '1' and `post_id` = 'post1'
```

How can I remove `` `post_id `` = '1'` to retrieve the corresponding comments?

Comment: How did you get the sql being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posts table the id column should be named id instead of post_id as this is what laravel expects. It is possible to set the primary key in your eloquent model to something other than id but it would be better to use id and follow the standard. Please refer to the docs here  http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent. Once you are naming your id column as id you can get the individual post by Post::find($id)

Comment: Thanks! I found it in the document that you may define a primaryKey property to override this convention. So how can I define the primary key? Is it the same way as laravel3? `public static $key = 'studentid';` I can't find an example in the doc.

Comment: It's now [`protected $primaryKey = 'some_id';`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L41)